# Are down votes on closed questions reclaimed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, down-votes

Sometimes I need to down vote a question because it is inappropriate or misconceived or just plain off-the-wall.  When I do this I will also initiate a close vote.

I have had the understanding that, upon question closure, down votes are automatically removed from my transcript.  But now I am wondering if this is the case.  Preserving a person's down votes for something that does not exist anymore seems out-of-whack to me.

What happens to the down votes if a question is closed?  Or alternatively, is there another point where down votes are removed from the voter's transcript?

Comment: I think most down votes are credited back, but not all (based on experience), but I don't know the criteria

Comment: I got one back the other day on a closed qusetion that had been deleted eventually by 'Community' (no answers I guess).  Not sure if you get it on closed questions with answers though. Comment not an answer as uncertain and can't find it on meta.

Comment: Your vote count as shown under "Votes Cast" will never decrease, even after the questions you voted on are deleted.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You get your points back if the question is **deleted** not if it's closed.

> •Reputation changes from bounties and votes (both up and down) on deleted posts (including answers to a deleted question) are nullified. (Exception: Reputation earned for posts with a score of three or higher, and where the post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days, is retained). - [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

That aside, I rarely find any overlap between "questions that should be closed" and "questions that should be downvoted". The possible exception would be a lazy no-research question that you can shoehorn into a close reason that really means "if you're not going to try neither are we." But why should I downvote a recipe request? It's offtopic on travel, but I don't need to downvote it, just close it. Similarly a dupe - in fact I've given upvotes to dupes if I think their wording makes for a great signpost over to the original. Unclear what you're asking? I would only downvote if I could be sure I'd come back and undo it after an edit, and I'm really not sure I ever would, so I settle for closing.

Comment: This is an incredibly sensible approach to iffy questions. Love it!